# Pydantic Checks on NewType

Tags: python, pydantic

I have created a new type with constraints for a project. (I know, the type itself is really not good at all,  but for now, that's what was used)

```
from typing import NewType
from pydantic import conlist, PositiveFloat    
PositionType = NewType('PositionType', conlist(PositiveFloat, min_items=2, max_items=2))
```

If I create a new, wrong instance of the type, I get no error

```
test = PositionType([2,-4])
```

However, if I create an instance of a BaseModel that uses this type, I get errors as expected.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List
class TestClass(BaseModel):
    list_of_positions : List[PositionType]

test = TestClass(list_of_positions=[test])
```

I want to be able to check if the new object is created correctly when a new instance of PositionType is used. Any ideas how to? I couldn't find a decorator/ option to run pydantic with
(I am on Python3.10)

Comment: If your new type is a list with exactly two positive floats, why don't just create a class that inherits from `BaseModel` with two positive float fields?

Comment: The list structure is not changed as of now, though I agree with the idea.
However, the problem itself (How to test the NewType I created) remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for some time, I ended up with this solution:
Pydantic allows defining a custom root type for classes:

```
from typing import NewType
from pydantic import conlist, PositiveFloat    
from pydantic import BaseModel
PositionType = NewType('PositionType', conlist(PositiveFloat, min_items=2, max_items=2))


class PositionClass(BaseModel):
    __root__: PositionType
    
test = PositionClass.parse_obj([2, -4])
```

When setting `__root__` to my new type, I get a class that is essentially the same as my NewType. Only when calling `PositionClass()`, I need to pass `__root__` as parameter or use the `parse_obj` function each pydantic class has.

Now I get the error messages I wanted (though I am not entirely happy with having to pass `__root__` to constructor)

Answer (score 0):

The argument names for [conlist](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.conlist:%7E:text=%2C%0A%20%20%20%20*%2C-,min_length,-%3DNone%2C) should be updated. min_items needs to be replaced with min_length and max_items with max_length.

```
PositionType = NewType('PositionType', conlist(PositiveFloat, min_length=2, max_length=2))
```